# Scrapy : How to parse same URL twice, check if results are identical and if not relaunch until two are identicals

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I've juste started web-**scraping** using Python and Scrapy.

I am trying to scrape data from numerous URLs from a website. The URL structure is always the as, so as the data within the page. Thus, the Spider was fairly easy to make and the **scraping** seems quite easy until now.

However I've noticed that, even if I use a proxy manager, some results I got from response differs from the ones I get if I visit the URL manually in my web browser. From what I have understand it might some kind of 'honeypot'.

I've thought about a way to bypass this problem :

- Get the same URL twice
- Compare the results values
- If they are similar validate them
- If not relaunch the request until I get a couple of identical value

I am unfortunately too limited for now to find a technical answer. How could make my spider always parse the same URL twice ? Should I use instead 2 spiders and compare results in an other way ?

Here the raw code of my spider :

```
import scrapy


def clean_prices(price_str : str):
    if price_str:
        return price_str.replace('\u202f','').replace(',','.').replace(" ","").replace("\xa0","").replace('\n','').replace('€','')
    else:
        return price_str

class PricesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "prices"
    download_delay = 2.5

    start_urls = [...]

    
    def parse(self, response):
        apart_cat_range = prices_cat.css("div.prices-summary__apartment-prices ul.prices-summary__price-range")

        
        yield {
            'prices' : clean_prices(apart_cat_range.css("li:nth-child(3)::text").get()).split("à")[1] if apart_cat_range.css("li:nth-child(3)::text").get() is not None else None
        }
```

Comment: Hi - I think you mean ‘scraping’ - ‘scrapping’ means throwing away, discarding.

Comment: Your `parse` routine can return Request objects that tell scrapy what additional pages to scrape.  It will not be easy to synchronize the new request with the existing one.  Are you sure it's not just the page getting updated?

Comment: @TimRoberts so with the parse I can't return the same request ? Won't it end in an infinite loop ?
Yes I'm sure it's not the page getting updated. I've triple checked.

Comment: If they are taking active anti-scraping steps, then I doubt you will succeed.  I can't really think of a good way to solve this problem.